# How to speed up development? (Lots of time wasted waiting for sails...)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sails.js

Development in sails is a pain! I have to wait... and wait... and wait... So much time wasted on waiting!

1. Each time I update a controller/model/config, I have to restart sails.js. Takes 25-35 seconds each time to reboot the server.
2. When I update a CSS/JS file, I hit refresh in the browser, and the changes don't appear! I assume in the background sails has to move the new files from /assets to /.tmp. But I have to wait 5-10 seconds for a simple CSS/JS change to appear! (I already have caching turned off in Google Console).

I don't mind #1 so much, I understand it's a necessity (I was spoiled all those years working with Apache/PHP where changes appeared instantly).

But #2 really gets to me. Is there any way to make this speed up? I can't possibly keep developing like this.

ie. make it serve files from /assets instead of /.tmp while in development?

ie. skip compiling and just serve the LESS/SASS files? etc...

Comment: Not sure why it's so slow for you - restarting Sails takes about 2 seconds for me. Are you lifting it as as prod? The CSS/JS changes also show for me instantly.

Comment: @KevinKao No I'm working in "development". Is sails maybe caching, and is there a way to disable cache?

Comment: @KevinKao I'm running `sails lift --dev --verbose` so now I see server messages. When I update a file, it now outputs `>> File "assets/styles/theme.css" changed`. Then Grunt messages appear (showing that asset compiler is running). Finally `Completed in 9.056s`. This verifies that each file I update requires compile. Is there any way to force it to use the /assets files directly instead?

Comment: Maybe my laptop is too slow... 2x2.1Ghz CPU with 4GB ram. I have 1CPU and 1GB ram allocated to the virtual box which is running the Ubuntu/node environment. Maybe if I had more CPU power it would be faster...?

Comment: I tried increasing the Virtual Box environment to use 2CPU and 2GB ram but it was still really slow. Don't know if more resources would speed it up, or if I bought a new computer, if that would be just wasted money. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try using node-inspector https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector with the `--save-live-edit` option. It's awesome as it allows you to live edit and save model/controller code in your browser, no restarts required. It doesn't help with client side js/css though. Here's my code FYI: `node /(path to node-inspector)/bin/inspector.js --save-live-edit &
sensible-browser http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 &&
sensible-browser http://localhost:1337/ &&
node --debug app.js`

Comment: You can solve #2 by adding 
`paths: {
   public: __dirname+'/../assets'
 },`
to your config/local.js